# Is there a text editor which displays column numbers and/or displays text in a grid to quickly glance column numbers?

Tags: text-editor, microsoft-excel, plain-text, notepad++

I basically need a text editor which displays text in a grid, so that I can know the exact column numbers of the text. The numerical simulation software I am using, TOUGH+ (written in FORTRAN), has a strict format and I need to specify my input files in the exact format. A letter misplaced here and there can make the whole file useless. So I need this to quickly glance at the input files, and know/verify which text starts and ends in which column. Otherwise, the file gets confusing sometimes.
For example in the image of the input file snippet, it's very difficult to separate at a glance where one value ends and other starts.
[image: Input file with line de-marking where one value starts and other ends]

I most useful thing I have tried is the TextFX plugin with Notepad++, but it is very inelegant, as in it just places a text of characters to see the column numbers.
[image: TextFX plugin]

The best way to describe my requirement would be Spredsheet but which takes only one character in a cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/) editor has features for it:

- option `"ruler_show": True` in user.json - this shows horizontal ruler on the top
- menu item "View - Toggle ruler"
- option `"margin_string": "30 40 50"` in user.json - this shows vertical lines at specified (space separated) columns.

[image: CudaText rulers]

To change color of vertical lines, use dialog in "Options / Settings-more / Settings - theme - ui"; change item `editor - margins - user defined`.